# GAC assembly reading registry - c#

Tags: c#, registry, 64-bit

I have an assembly that installed in the GAC. Can this assembly access registry values in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\COMPANYNAME`

I do not get any error but am not able to read subkey from above path. My assembly is strongly signed.

Reason I am using registry is because use of config file is not permitted.

Sample code

```
string regKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\COMPANYNAME";
string userGUID = (string)Registry.GetValue(regKey, "userGUID", "-1");
```

Comment: @SteveWellens and the +1, did you read the question?

Comment: Before, when it said `I do not get any error...`

Comment: I mis-read it so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @user721264 Are you running on a 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running 64-bit OS and your assembly is x86, or called by a x86 process, then your registry call is redirected to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\COMPANYNAME` node. This can be the source of your problem.

Comment: I am developing on x32, so I added the registry to my system and generated the .reg file to run on the x64 machine. The data in the .reg file is
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MYCOMPANY]
"userGUID"="156789092267839"

on the x64 machine I can find this path using regedit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\COMPANYNAME

Comment: Yes, but any access from a 32-bit app to registry will be redirected to `Wow6432Node` subnode tree. Try to create `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MYCOMPANY] "userGUID"="156789092267839"` on x64 machine, and see if it works. P.S. there is no such thing as `x32` it's either `x86` which is 32-bit or `x64` which is 64-bit.